# I want regex who match letters anywhere in string

Tags: regex

I look for regex who match:
nep,enp,pen and all combination of this letters [p,e,n] with length 3.
**Ignore ben,pencil,enp444,ven, etc.**

p|e|n doesn't help me because i can have words with length 20 and this method is not good for me.

Should match every letter so pee,nee doesn't work.

Comment: This [`^[pen]{3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/DNkepc/1)?

Comment: @ctwheels Would also match `ppp`…

Comment: @deceze exactly. OP specified *all combinations*

Comment: @deceze OP did say "all combinations of the letters "p, e, n" with length 3.  "ppp", to me, satisfies that.

Comment: That's somewhat vague. Colloquially I'd understand that as "shuffle those three letters into any order", not "any strings which are a subset of this set". It's up to OP to clarify…

Comment: I forgot to say should match every letter so ^[pen]{3}$ match pee,nee

Comment: @deceze I completely agree. And the OP should also specify which language this is for as, if the case is to shuffle the letters, it's best not to do this with regex.

Comment: `^(pen|epn|npe|pne|enp|nep)$` may be brute-force, but seems so obvious that I wonder why it's not mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: Sanely this should be done as `[pen]{3}`, followed by a separate step that confirms that all of the letters are unique. How to do this exactly depends on the language used. In pure regex this is needlessly painful.

Comment: @TeodorKalev do you want to match `pee` and `nee` yes or no? Also, **which language**: Python, PHP, Java, C#, etc?

Answer (score 1):

here it is!

`((?:([nep])(?!\2)([nep])(?!\3))(?!\2)[nep])`

basically:

`([nep])(?!\2)` search for `n` or `e` or `p` not followed by the same letter

`([nep])(?!\3)` do the same as before, in this way we have first letter different from the second and the second letter different from the third... but this allow a something similar to `pep`... so we add a group saying that the third letter must be different from the first `(?:([nep])(?!\2)([nep])(?!\3))(?!\2)` and the we add the last letter [nep] and a matching group surrounding all

you can see this in action here: https://regex101.com/r/uoqCbG/2